# Recommended view framework for ruby

Tags: ruby

Anyone have a framework/system to recommend to "show" (views) of ruby objects?

- ruby objects will be deeply nested
- a subset of the objects will be persisted (say 20%).
- rails -- don't think so, [everything] (or say 80/20) seems to be "on" a record. Looking for persistence not to dominate the design.
- Ramaze -- quick look -- again seemed to be all about objects living on records
- Webby -- I think (maybe?) it has zero persistence/database (that wouldn't work of course)

Basically, framework to popup views on ruby, and simple api for database (when needed)
thank you....

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking for. Perhaps you could add some examples or some links to similar things you want to imitate?

Comment: Is it going to be web-based, console-based or a GUI desktop application?

Comment: Web-based. As just a small example of maybe the type of objects, let's just say a simple unit converter and supporting objects, with a simple conversion, or more complex sets of conversions (matrices), lists of quantities to convert, etc. Not too hard to do in ruby, as only a little persistence is required, so would like to use, if available, thin view framework, and thin db framework.

Comment: I do not understand why wouldn't you use Rails for this. It can be argueed as an overkill, though, It is also where you will get the best documentation and plugins...

Answer (score 3):

From the brief description and the last comment you added, it seems like Sinatra would be the perfect fit for you:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/

If then one day you need a bit more, you can use Padrino, which builds on Sinatra and let's you pick and choose the other parts you neeed (ORM, test framework etc):

http://www.padrinorb.com/

Comment: Padrino is probably more indicated, since persistence is a requirement.

Comment: Nothing stopping you from including gems in your Sinatra app. I persist my data in MongoDB for example.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thank you. Just a quick glance, views looks pretty clear, not yet sure on persistance approach data mapper maybe, or will try MongoDB as you mention. **thank you much.

Comment: Tried -- but looks like I need to wait i.e. until tomorrow to award bounty -- again thank you